# Structuring my website files with third-party applications

Tags: javascript, css, web

I have a site with this structure:

```
\
|--css
|  \
|  |--vendors
|  |  \
|  |  |--normalize.css
|  |  |--...
|  |
|  |--styles.css
|  |--media-queries.css
|
|--js
|  \
|   |--vendors
|   |  \
|   |  |--jquery.js
|   |  |--jquery.plugin.js
|   |  |--...
|   |
|   |--script.js
| 
|--img
|--index.html
```

The case is this, now I want to incorporate a slider that comes in a folder with your own pictures, css and js files, all sorted into subfolders. Where do I locate it?. It seems it would not be right to separate files containing folder of their own. What do you suggest?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly I order files per library. It's much easier to manage since you can simple drop one in or remove one. In your case you have to search inside every folder to pick files that are part of a library.

```
|-- assets
|  |
|  +-- jquery
|  |    |
|  |    +- jquery.js
|  |
|  +-- other library
|       |
|       +- style.css
|       +- behaviors.js
|
+-- index.html
```

Comment: If it is possible, but the folders css, js, img should be at the root of the site, to make the structure clearer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MauricioPanuncio It's a matter of opinion. I don't think those folders should be at the root for a clear structure. The only one who cares about the structure is the developer and as a developer I like to know where my libraries are and what files are associated with it.